# Transition HTML element from center in CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to animate height property of an element using CSS but I want it from the center. Below is my code but it changes height from bottom.

```css
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.left-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  animation: height 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes height {
  from {
    height: 60px;
  }
  to {
    height: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="left-border"></div>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j2refncs/1/)

Comment: What do you mean by you want it from center? Can you give more clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I use animation `top` instead of `height`. The red toggle also needs a 'container' now so I just used the one you had there. When changing the dimensions of the red toggle, change the outer wrapper, not the toggle element (it will fit to whatever the container is, both width and height wise)

https://jsfiddle.net/j2refncs/7/

```
.toggle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;

  .left-border {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 200px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    animation: height 2s;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes height {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 30px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform`

```
from {
}
to {
  transform: scaleY(0.1666);
}
```

`0.1666` comes from `10px` / `60px`

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the `top` with the `height` to make the height change appear from the center:

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.left-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  animation: height 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes height {
  from {
    top: 25px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  to {
    top: 50px;
    height: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="left-border"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use [`transform: scaleY()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) in the animation. The default [transform origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) is the center.

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.left-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  animation: height 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes height {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY(0.167);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="left-border"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `top: 75px` to the *keyframe* since the change in `height` is `50px`. You want to reduce the `height` by *25px* or half from both sides, *top* and *bottom*, to come to the desired `10px`. So *50px / 2* + `top: 50px` = `top: 75px`:

```css
.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.left-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px; /* starting position from the top */
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background-color: #f00;
  animation: height 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes height {
  to {height: 10px; top: 75px} /* + ending position from the top */
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="left-border"></div>
</div>
```